# Match the 'day of week' integer between PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, dayofweek

I cannot decide on the best method to match the 'day of week' number between MySQL and PHP

**PHP**

```
$date =  strtotime('2014-02-15');
$day_number = $day_of_week = date("w", $date);
$day = $day_of_week = date('l', $date);

echo $day." ".$day_number;
```

Output: Saturday 6

**MySQL**

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(  '2014-02-15' );
```

Output: 7

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(  '2014-02-15' );
```

Output: 5

Is there a way to match these numbers up without writing my own custom function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well `DAYOFWEEK` has the following responses:  (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday)

And in php `date('w');` has the following responses: 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

So you could just use `date('w') + 1` and get the same answer in both.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: Ok for `date('w') + 1` is equivalent to `DAYOFWEEK` but `date('N') % 7` seems not correct (for sunday, it returns 0 whereas DAYOFWEEK returns 1)

Comment: @AlterPHP yeah you are correct, not sure how I mixed that up and no one else caught it

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(  '2014-02-15',  '%w' )
```

Output: 6

(For reference, `2014-02-15` was a Saturday)